# Como identificar la función que llama a una goroutines en golang?

Tags: go, heap, runtime

Necesito crear un arbol de llamadas de manera que cada llamada sea un nodo en el arbol. Estoy obteniendo el nombre del caller y de la función actual mediante el stack trace, pero no provee ningún tipo de identificador por llamada.

```
    stack := make([]byte, 1024)
    length := runtime.Stack(stack, false)
    stacktrace := (string)(stack[:length])
```

Hay alguna manera de asociar una función con la función que la invocó?
Por ejemplo que en el siguiente programa pueda diferenciar las dos llamadas a A() y las funciones que invocan tipo C0-B0-A0 y C1-B1-A1?

```
func A(){
   go B()
}

func B(){
   C()
}

func C(){
   //do something
}

func main(){
    A()
    A()
}
```